# cd not working on a directory

Tags: linux, unix, cd

I see "builds01" directory when I do ls,when I "cd builds01" on that directory I get the following error,any idea why I am getting below error for a directory that exists/s

```
<user:/prj/com/builds>ls -la
total 8
dr-xr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2013-05-29 00:53 .
dr-xr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 2013-05-29 00:53 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 2013-05-29 00:53 builds01
<user:/prj/qca/builds>cd builds01/
-bash: cd: builds01/: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out user permissions: you are not root at the moment. 
The folder is readable only by root (and belongs to root).

Comment: how to change the userpermissions,i want to change it to a different user other than root

Comment: try with `sudo chown -R gnakkala builds01`

Comment: You wouldn't get a `No such file or directory` error, but a `Permission denied` error

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue once such as this. It’s possible that this is on mount point and not a real directory. Another possibility is there may be white space before the name of the directory that was somehow created.

Try to do: `cd \ builds01` or even `cd “builds01”` and see if that works.
If all else fails attempt to use something such as *filezilla* or *winscp* and navigate to the path.

Comment: It is more likely to be spaces after the name, or perhaps backspaces in the name...but I think that you're likely right that the trouble is that the `builds01` directory's name is not just 8 characters long.  Try using `ls | od -c` to look at the output.  One other possibility: you've got `$CDPATH` set and it does not start `$CDPATH=:...` with a leading colon.